# Year and century being swapped when inserting a date into Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net

I have the following table in Oracle:

```
create table tb_dates ( dt_date date )
```

and the following code in C#:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataColumn dc = new DataColumn();
dc.DataType = Type.GetType("System.DateTime");
dc.ColumnName = "dt_date";
dt.Columns.Add(dc);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["dt_date"] = System.DateTime.Now;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}

using (OracleBulkCopy bulkCopy = new OracleBulkCopy("data source=orcl;user id=scott;password=tiger", OracleBulkCopyOptions.Default))
{
    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "tb_dates";
    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
}
```

The dates in the table must be 2014/05/15. But, when I do the select in Oracle, I have 1420/05/15. The year has been reversed.

I'm using Oracle 11g and the Oracle ODP.NET 12 client. What I have to do for this code work correctly?

Comment: Just to clarify, you're inserting the current date into Oracle from C#. When you then select the date, directly on the database and not through C# the year is incorrect?

Comment: In C# the year is correct. The problem is when I check the values of the table in the database after the bulkcopy. I'm trying to set in C# the Oracle Globalization:
OracleGlobalization info = OracleGlobalization.GetClientInfo();
info.TimeStampFormat = "DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF AM";
info.TimeStampTZFormat = "DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF AM TZR";
OracleGlobalization.SetThreadInfo(info);

But I get the same result.

Before I change the formats OracleGlobalization the year have the format RR

Comment: info.DateFormat will control date formats whereas info.TimeStampFormat and info.TimeStampTZFormat are for timestamps which are not the same as dates in Oracle.